# Building a service with spark and spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rabbitmq, spark-streaming

I have read a bit about spark streaming and I would like to know if its possible to stream data from a custom source with rabbitmq as a broker and feed this data through the spark stream where Spark’s machine learning and graph processing algorithms will be performed on them and send it to other filesystems/databases/dashboards or customer receivers.

P.S I code with python, I do not have any experience using spark and Can I call what I'm trying to achieve a microservice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I feel spark Structured streaming is more suitable and easy to implement rather than spark-streaming. Spark Structured Streaming follows the below concept

> Source(read from RabbitMQ) -- Transformation (apply ML algo) -- Sink
> (write to database)

You can refer [this](https://github.com/kaantas/spark-twitter-sentiment-analysis/blob/master/twitter_topic_avg_sentiment_val.py) github project for an example on Spark structured streaming.

I don't think there is an inbuilt spark connector which can consume from rabbitMq. I know there is one for Kafka but you can write your own custom source and sink (Writing this without any spark knowledge might be tricky).

You can start this as a spark-job and you have to create a wrapper service layer which triggers this as a spark job ([spark job launcher](https://riptutorial.com/apache-spark/example/25927/sparklauncher)) or use [spark rest api](https://gist.github.com/arturmkrtchyan/5d8559b2911ac951d34a)

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html

Comment: I am planning to learn spark. I wanted to know if it was possible to build something like that with spark and the process of building it

Comment: yup!! you could do this in spark.